# Unable to renew random number on python

Tags: python, random, numbers

I'm  new to python programming and I'm trying to do a simple command line game. Basically the command line asks for a number from 1 to 3, the user gives the number, the command line then compares it to a random number and decides if the winner passes or not, if he passes the hole thing repeats until he misses the number. My problem is renewing the random number for the next fase! I need a new random number for each time the command line compares it to the user's number.

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#ChooseADoor

from random import randint
import time
import sys
print("Welcome mortal, to the Choose a door game...")
Score = 0
StrScore = str(Score)

#DeathDoor = 0
#DeathDoor = randint(1,3)



tutorialRequired = input("Would you like to go through the tutorial? (YES / NO): ")

if tutorialRequired == "YES":
    print("""Alright mortal, you were kidnaped and you wake up in a room.
There are 3 doors, two of them let you continue,
one of them gives you a painful death...
Yeah, sorry about that...
    """)
    ready = input("Ready mortal? (YES / NO): ")
    if ready =="YES":
        print("Starting game in 3...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("2...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("1...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("GO!")
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("Goodbye mortal.")
        sys.exit()
else:
    print("""Alright smarty pants let's see if you live to tell your story...
    """)
    ready = input("Ready mortal? (YES / NO): ")
    if ready =="YES":
        print("Starting game in 3...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("2...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("1...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("GO!")
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("Goodbye mortal.")
        sys.exit()


while Score < 10:

    print("Three doors ahed... ")
    door = input("Pick one (1, 2, 3): ")
    doorNum = int(door)


    if door in ("123"):
        DeathDoor = 0
        DeathDoor = randint(1,3)

        if DeathDoor == door:

            print("End of line, mortal.")
            print("You passed", StrScore, ("doors until the endo of your miserable life..."))

            break
        else:
            RandomNum = 0
            RandomNum = randint(1,3)
            if RandomNum == 1:
                print("You're safe for now, mortal. Go on.")
                DeathDoor = 0
                Score = (Score + 1)
                StrScore = str(Score)
                print("Score: " + StrScore)
            elif RandomNum == 2:
                print(" Beginner's luck. Let's see if you laugh next time mortal.")
                DeathDoor = 0
                Score = (Score + 1)
                StrScore = str(Score)
                print("Score: " + StrScore)
            elif RandomNum == 3:
                print(" Keep the fireworks, they may be useful for your funeral. Go on.")
                DeathDoor = 0
                Score = (Score + 1)
                StrScore = str(Score)
                print("Score:" + StrScore)

    else:
        print("Don't try to fool me,")
        print("goodbye mortal.")
        StrScore = str(Score)
        print("You passed " + StrScore + (" doors until the endo of your miserable life..."))
        time.sleep(1)
        sys.exit()

StrScore = str(Score)
print("Congratulations mortal, you live. For now."))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually getting a new random number every loop. Your problem is here:

```
...
if DeathDoor == door:
...
```

You are comparing an integer to a string, which always yields `False`. The correct way is

```
if DeathDoor == int(door)
```

Also resetting `RandomNum` and `DeathDoor` to zero is unecessary.

Since you are just beginning to learn Python, you should consider reading https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/, the Python style guide. If you follow the rules in the guide from the start, your code will be much easier to understand (not only for others but also for you).

Comment: Thank you very much! Yeah, I also thought my code was a bit of a mess but I just didn't know what was the right way, thank you for the link too!